# how to create node app listen on host entry domain ?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, express

Suppose I have created three entries in /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 domain1.com
127.0.0.1 domain2.com
127.0.0.1 domain3.com
```

I want my three node apps to listen request on this domains that i have created .How can i implement it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-rok for this purpose. Follow these steps to achieve this :

1. Install rgrok globally from [NG-ROK](https://ngrok.com/.)
   This is a module by which you can server your local server over the Internet. It will generates a temporary url for your server and forward all the requests to your node server.
2. Now you have to start your node server(Assuming you have started already).
3. Now you have to map your server port with command : `ngrok http <<YOUR_PORT_NUMBER>>`
4. You will get a temporary URL for this server. Now repeat the same 2nd & 3rd step for all of you servers.

Comment: ohh thats perfect i forgot i use it on daily basis.

Comment: Small nitpick: it is not NG-ROK or ng-rok. You pronounce it as "en-grok". See https://ngrok.com/faq#name

Comment: Thanks for this @JoostVunderink

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

file and do the entries there.

Here is a sample entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
ServerName local.domain1.com     #or whatever
<Directory "/var/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

DocumentRoot is the directory where you are keeping your `index.html` file.

After this, run this command:

```
a2ensite 000-default.conf
```

and

```
service apache2 reload
```

PS: if this gives an error regarding Rewrite something, (I don't remember the exact error), run this command:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```